# Is there a name for replacing @ with "at" and . with "dot"?

Tags: email, internet

Many users and forum programs in attempt to make automatic e-mail address harvesting harder modify them replacing @ character with "at" and . character with "dot".

So that

```
team@example.com
```

becomes

```
team at example dot com
```

Is there any special term for this practice?

Comment: Wow. Using other people's email address in a question about munging... (Changed to example.com as per RFC 2606, hoping bots don't get into the revisions.)

Comment: Is this really such a problem? The original address has been on each page of this site for ages. That's specifically why I chose it - it's already here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As well as obfuscation, it is often referred to less formally as "munging".

Answer (score 9):

[Obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation)?

> Obfuscation is the concealment of
>   intended meaning in communication,
>   making communication confusing,
>   intentionally ambiguous, and more
>   difficult to interpret.

**Edit:** Of course, in this case we're talking about making the communication confusing for spambots, and not for humans.

Comment: Y3s 1nd33d.

Comment: Well it can be a little confusing for humans too. It's easier to skim some text looking for "x@y" than "x at y".

Answer (score 7):

**Anti-Spambot [Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encoding)** ?

Of course the opposite then would be 'Anti-spambot Decoding' ;-)

But on a more serious note: I think @David is right with his 'munging'.
Even more specifically: **[Address munging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_munging)** would be the right term (according to Wikipedia).

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider it a form of [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captcha). The Turing test being not so much the transformation "at"==@ and "dot"=dot, but finding and recognizing such disguised email addresses in a text that contains lots of other "at"s and perhaps even a few "dot"s.